# Any difference between "a change of heart" and "a change of mind"?

Tags: meaning

What does "a change of heart" mean in the following newspaper article?
Is there any difference between "a change of heart" and "a change of mind?"

> Mr. Comey’s willingness to discuss the threat in public was something of a **change of heart**. As F.B.I. director, he supervised counterintelligence investigations into computer break-ins that harvested emails from the State Department and the White House, and that penetrated deep into the computer systems of the Joint Chiefs of Staff.

Source: [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/10/us/politics/trump-comey-russia-fbi.html?_r=0)

Comment: They roughly mean the same thing, but "change of heart" implies a more emotionally motivated change, while "change of mind" suggests a more mechanical/practical motivation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe they have more or less the same meaning, though I can't say I have ever heard the phrase "a change of mind". I am more familiar with a slightly different form, "... had changed my mind", versus "... had a change of heart".

"I have changed my mind" can be used a bit more broadly, to reflect a change in a specific decision or a general position.

Where as "I have had a change of heart" usually refers to the change of a specific position on a subject or attitude.

Also, note the difference in the phrasing "I **have changed** my mind" versus "I **have had a change** in heart"

Comment: The answer is good, but missing the information in @Hot Licks answer